# Error "The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value" with App Service Certificate

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have created in my Azure Key Vault a secret containing an ssl certificate converted from .pfx to base64 string. Now I try to use it to create a certificate linked to an App Service using bicep file.

```
resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: 'mykeyvault'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    tenantId: tenantId
    sku: {
      name: 'standard'
      family: 'A'
    }   
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    accessPolicies: [...]
  }
}

resource sslCertificateSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: '${kv.name}/sslcert'
  properties: {
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
    }
    value: <base64_string_ssl>
    contentType: 'application/x-pkcs12'
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'myServiceplan'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {  
    name: 'B1'
  }
}

resource sslCertificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'myCertificate'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: <my_keyvaultId>
    keyVaultSecretName: <my_keyvaultCertificateSecretName>
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    
  }
}
```

I also tried to import the certificate manually in the key vault and reexport it to ensure the base64 string was correct and it seemed ok.

However I am getting the error "The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value."

Do you have an idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Does your certificate require a password ?

Comment: Yes, I used it to generated the base64 string. I also tried to pass the password in the certificate definition but I get the same error, I thought it was used in combination with the pfxBlob property which I do not use since I want to get the certificate from the key vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure KeyVault as a solution for secure storage of confidential information.
Two ways to authenticate a web application in KeyVault. A better is approach is to **authenticate the web application using a certificate**. This certificate is also deployed directly from KeyVault. This means neither the confidential information nor the keys to the vault are ever disclosed.

Please check the below steps:

Click on the below link to know steps of ***create certificate linked with app service from keyVault***.
[Loading the access certificate for your application into KeyVault](https://alexduggleby.com/2017/04/17/azure-keyvault-authenticating-with-certificates-and-reading-secrets/)

---

**Check the File Formats of Certificates which is the major building block when importing certificates**

PEM & PFX are the supported certificate formats in Azure Key Vault resource.

• `.pem` file format consists of 1 or more X509 certificate files.

• A server certificate (issued for your domain), a matching private key, and an optional intermediate CA can all be stored in a single file using the `.pfx` archive file format.

The first step is to convert any certificates used by the App Service to (and label them as) application/x-pkcs12. It might be possible to resolve the issue by reimport the certificate from a pfx file with the —password parameter (***az keyvault certificate import***), and then import it from the key vault to the webapp. You could use this blog as a resource.

Also, look if Cert and the Key Vault are in their original resource group.

References:

1. [Azure Key Vault Import Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate) provided by Microsoft and GitHub Source of [Deploying Azure Web App Certificate using KV](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/24/Deploying-Azure-Web-App-Certificate-through-Key-Vault.html)

---

If you missed the certificate policy on upload and if generating new certificates, then try to generate in the key vault itself.

```php
$credential = Get-Credential

login-azurermaccount -Credential $credential
$vaultName = 'my-vault-full-of-keys'
$certificateName = 'my-new-cert'
$policy = New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SubjectName "CN=mememe.me" -IssuerName Self -ValidityInMonths 120
Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName -CertificatePolicy $policy
```

---

> "The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value"

1. Please check that you have given permission to access the key vault for Resource Provider

Use PowerShell to enable the '**`Microsoft.Web`**' Resource Provider directly access the azure key Vault.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount 
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

2. Sometimes this problem exists in the step of how the certificate was uploaded to the Key Vault: If using PowerShell, give full path instead of the relative path to the cert when uploading.
   `$pfxFilePath = "PFX_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH"` # Change this path

Example:

```
$pfxFilePath = "F:\KeyVault\PrivateCertificate.pfx"
$pwd = "[2+)t^BgfYZ2C0WAu__gw["
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable 
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection  
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag) 
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12 
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType) 
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes) 
$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $fileContentEncoded -AsPlainText –Force 
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12' 
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName akurmitestvault -Name keyVaultCert -SecretValue $Secret -ContentType $secretContentType # Change the Key Vault name and secret name
```

---

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem! It seems I did not convert my ssl certificate to base64 correctly, with your solution it worked well.